# How to align an EditText on button click

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java, so apologies for any incorrect Jargon. I have the following code which references two buttons and correspond it to an EditText. How would I go about aligning the EditText to the right on button click?

I have tried setTextAlignment but was receiving a `cannot resolve symbol` error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Creating button references for the buttons corresponding to their IDs through findViewById
        Button rB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rButton);
        Button lB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lButton);
        //Register click event with first button
        rB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);//Correspond the text view to its ID
                //Align edittext to the right
            }
        });
        //Register click event with second button
        lB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText); //Correspond the text view to its ID
                //Align edittext to the left
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: @Elye I think he wants to align the EditText left or right depending on which button the user clicked. Can that be done in XML?

Comment: Have two EditText in your layout file with initial visibility state set to gone. Place them next to each button. Depending on the button clicked, set visibility of the appropriate EditText to Visible in your code.

Comment: you want entire edit text to be aligned or the text inside the edit text should be aligned. ? Kindly specify clearly.

Comment: @RaguSwaminathan I want the text inside the edit text to be aligned

Comment: so whenever u click the button, text inside the edit text should be right and left aligned accordingly..?? correct